# Problems Sorting in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, formulas

I have read answers here to the question of sorting in Excel and having formulas not working.  But the answers do not seem to help in my particular case.

I am a `soapmaker` and use Excel to calculate my recipes. The oils are listed alphabetically. I plug in the amount of oil I want to use.

I have formulas at the bottom of the spreadsheet to determine the ratio of solid oils to liquid and the ratio of some of the other oil combos.

Once I have the recipe I want to use, I want to sort the oils by quantity so that I can more easily make my labels, listing ingredients in order of amount used.

When I sort, the formulas at the bottom get all messed up.  Putting `$` in the formulas for the cell references does not help. I'm fairly Excel-savvy and that was the first thing I thought of.

I suppose could name the cells, but I have so many oils listed (30+) that that's prohibitive and I may add more in the future.

The calculations I want are quite simple yet I've tried all the methods I can think of and it's still not working.  Help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions that could work, but as you've seen keeping static formulas below data you are sorting, is not usually going to work well. Here's something to consider:

If you can, ALWAYS group related data and formulas in a SINGLE ROW. This means for example, moving your formulas to the end of each row so they move around when the data moves around in sorting. Most people go wrong by trying to make it look pretty - but this is the most organized. Go for what's functional.

Your other alternative is to use Excel 2007+ tables (google search) - but I suspect from your description that you're pointing to specific rows and those can't be tracked without using VLookup. So that's your other alternative - Vlookup (google search - dozens of examples out there). You're basically writing a formula to dynamically find the correct row, no matter where it is (landed after sorting)

I really recommend my first option though, keep your formulas in the same rows. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to offer suggestions.  I will consider modifying my layout but since I'm comparing information on separate rows, I'm not sure moving my formulas is the answer.  The simplest thing I've found to do is to calc everything, getting my ratios where they need to be and then cutting and pasting 'values' before sorting.  Very primative, but effective - as long as I remember that I can't tweak anything after that.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Shanda Barnett glad to help - perhaps if you added a screenshot of some kind, we could offer more suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Move your data TO ABOVE the sort area.  I do this when I have subtotals and other row based calculations, so that when I sort I don't have any issues.

I also suggest moving your label functions to a rank formula and use an Array formula to look up the unique combination, along with the Congatenate functions, so you don't have to worry about sort functions in your sheet.